# In Outlook REST API how can I set BodyType to Text

Tags: outlook-restapi

I EWS, I was able to specify BodyType = 'Text' when querying email messages. Is there any alternative to this in Outlook REST api?

I tried to use [PidTagBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee158918(EXCHG.80).aspx) property which is a plain text representation of message body, but it just seems to be empty for all messages with Html body type.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, even the Outlook add-in API allows to specify coercionType='text'. Would be nice to have this option in REST API.